# Check if value is in array using in_array

Tags: php

I have a `$result` array like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [group_id] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [group_id] => 9 ) [2] => Array ( [group_id] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [group_id] => 14 ) [4] => Array ( [group_id] => 16 ) [5] => Array ( [group_id] => 21 ) )
```

I need to check if `9` is in this array as part of `group_id`:

```
if(in_array(9, $result)){
        echo "It is there";
    } else{
        echo "It's not there";
    }
```

But this always returns:

> It's not there.

Comment: try use `array_search`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your array structure will remain same then use

```
$a = Array ( [0] => Array ( [group_id] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [group_id] => 9 ) [2] => Array ( [group_id] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [group_id] => 14 ) [4] => Array ( [group_id] => 16 ) [5] => Array ( [group_id] => 21 ) ) ;

    $result = array_column($a, 'group_id'); 
    if(in_array(9, $result)){
        echo "It is there";
    } else{
        echo "It's not there";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array_map` instead of `array_column`.This solution not depends on 'group_id' key.

```
if(in_array(9, array_map('current', $array))){
    echo "It is there";
} else{
    echo "It's not there";
}
```